# Javascript loop for estructure

Tags: javascript

i have to solve the following function: "x" represent a number of cycles. One cycle sums +1 and then multiply the result *2. For example:

```
0 cycles = 0 + 1 = 1 (result)
1 cycles = 1 * 2 = 2 (result)
2 cycles = 2 + 1 = 3 (result)
3 cycles = 3 * 2 = 6 (result)
4 cycles = 6 + 1 = 7 (result) and so on.
```

I have this function:

```
function final(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var result = x[i] * 2 + 1
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: If `x` is the number of cycles, what is the reason behind `x[i]` ?

Comment: what is `x[i]` when you have `< x` on the loop? Is x an array and you need the length or what?

Comment: Lookup "recursion" or recursive functions...

Comment: Can you explain a bit, if x = 3, what should the final output be? will it only be 6 or will it include the result of cycle 0,1 and 2?

Comment: It looks like you want a function that alternates between two different actions: on odd-numbered invocations it adds one to the argument, and on even-number invocations it doubles the argument. Can you confirm that, or if it's not true, state what is actually required more clearly?

Comment: The function should add +1 to the result of the double of the prior result and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, the solution finally was this:

```
function final(x){
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
if (i % 2 === 0){
result = result * 2 + 1;}
else{
result = (result + 1);}
}
return result+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the results, you can use answer by @Kornflexx. If not, you can directly calculate the value :

```
function final (x) {
  var t = (4 << (x / 2)) - 2;
  return x % 2 ? t : t / 2;
}
```

Note that if x is large you will quickly pass the int limit and would then need to deal with big integers

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you don't care of the fact that the for start at 1.

```
function final(x) {
    var result = [];
    result[0] = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        result[i] = i % 2 ? result[i - 1] * 2  : result[i - 1] + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only require the final result of the function then the following will achieve that for you.

```
function final(x) {
    var result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            result = result + 1;
        } else {
            result = result * 2;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer if he doesn't want to store the results.

Comment: @Kornflexx mine is more efficient ;)

Comment: @Juvian yep yours is way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, you can have this short form

```js
function final(x) {
  var result = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    result = x % 2 == 0 ? result + 1 : result * 2
  }
  console.log(x,result)
  return result;
}

final(3)
```